# How Fix Footer at the bottom of the page even if there is no element present?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

1. I am using a react bowler plate and trying to make a landing page, When I manage to get the footer at the bottom of the page all the elements get behind the footer:
   [image]

as you can see the page is scrolling but the footer is fixed and not scrolling down.

2. I have also tried different CSS when there are no elements above the footer to push the footer down, it will render in the middle of the screen.

[image]

I have tried different CSS to display the footer on the bottom of the screen but can't find a way.

- Elements push the footer down, if the elements are removed the footer is displayed at the center of the screen and if I fix the footer at the bottom of the page it overlaps the elements and is not pushed down.

**Footer CSS:**

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Face from "../Img/facebook.svg";
import Insta from "../Img/instagram.svg";
import Twi from "../Img/twitter.svg";
import Google from "../Img/google.png";
import Paypal from "../Img/paypal.png";
import Stand from "../Img/stand.png";
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Bigdiv>
        <StyledUpperFooter>
          <h4>Subscribe to our Newsetter</h4>
          <div className="Email">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Type in your email.."
              autocomplete="off"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </StyledUpperFooter>
        <Foot>
          <Grid>
            <Row>
              <h1>Chalo</h1>
              <p>
                <img src={Face} /> <img src={Insta} />
                <img src={Twi} />
              </p>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <h4>Information</h4> <div>Home</div> <div>Explore</div>
              <div>Travel</div>
              <div>Blog</div>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <h4>Helpfull Links</h4> <div>Destinations</div> <div>Support</div>
              <div>Terms&Conditions</div> <div>Privacy</div>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <h4>Contact</h4> <div>+62 21 6531 4171</div>
              <div>info@travel.com</div>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <h4>Payments</h4>
              <p>
                <img src={Paypal} />

                <img src={Stand} />

                <img src={Google} />
              </p>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </Foot>
      </Bigdiv>
    </>
  );
};
const Bigdiv = styled.section`
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
`;
const StyledUpperFooter = styled.section`
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  h4 {
    margin-left: 2.75rem;
  }
  span {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  label,
  input {
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  label {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  input {
    color: black;
    width: auto;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
  }
  input[type="submit"] {
    margin-right: 8rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    width: auto;
    background: #85552a;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: right;
  }
  input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-color: #72fad8;
  }
  input[type="submit"]:active {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  input[type="submit"]:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
`;
const Foot = styled.div`
  background-color: #381d09;
  color: white;
  padding: 8% 8% 8% 8%;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
`;

const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
`;
const Row = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 50px));
  img {
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
  }
`;

export default Footer;
```

**Elements above the foot CSS:**

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Review from "./Review";
const ReviewSection = () => {
  return (
    <StyledTestimonials>
      <div className="testimonial-headings">
        <span>Comments</span>
        <h1>Client Says</h1>
      </div>
      <Review />
    </StyledTestimonials>
  );
};
const StyledTestimonials = styled.section`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  div.testimonial-headings {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: 30px 0px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    h1 {
      font-size: 2.2rem;
      font-weight: 500;
      background-color: black;
      color: wheat;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    span {
      font: 1.3rem;
      color: #252525;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  }
`;
export default ReviewSection;
```

**Gobal Style:**

```js
 *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
          
        }
```

**Main Page:**

```js
import React from "react";
import Footer from "../Components/Footer";
import NavBar from "../Components/NavBar";
import ReviewSection from "../Components/ReviewSection";
const LandingPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <ReviewSection />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export  default  LandingPage ;
```

Comment: Please add code

Comment: Please share the code

Answer (score 1):

**In your `ReviewSection` component give it a `min-height` to your `StyledTestimonials`**

Se `min-height` to the desired minimum height of your web's body:

```
const StyledTestimonials = styled.section`
  display: flex;
  min-height: 1400px; // <-- Pick the number by your desired
...The rest
```

`min-height` is the property to limit the minimum height of your element, this will stop your `footer` to go too close to the navbar:

```css
.review {
  min-height: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">NavBar</div>
<div class="review">Review</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```